# Do I really need to learn all controller classess?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I started learning spring MVC And in controller there is list of 14 classes below:

1. SimpleFormController
2. AbstractController
3. AbstractCommandController
4. CancellableFormController
5. AbstractCommandController
6. **MultiActionController**
7. ParameterizableViewController
8. ServletForwardingController
9. ServletWrappingController
10. UrlFilenameViewController
11. AbstractController
12. AbstractCommandController
13. SimpleFormController
14. CancellableFormController

Do I really need to go through all of them? or **@Controller (i.e.MultiActionController)** is sufficient?
I think all these classes belongs to very old versions of Spring framework and now a days we don't need to learn them. Need Guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten by with just `@Controller` on my Spring Boot projects.
I can't think of a case where you need to worry about which class is auto-wired by the annotation, unless you need to write your own implementation for a specific application flow which uses that specific controller. And, again, I've never had to do this. I only have 1 year of experience with Spring in production, however, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing your experience :)